# How to cancel operation queue in another view controller

Tags: ios

I have many image uploading operation queues running in background, and assigned name to each of them, but I would like to cancel the operation queue in its corresponding view controller. How can I get the queue task? can I get it by queue name? or what is the common way to cancel a running operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to cancel your queue at specific point, When you don't want to more operations.

Please give a comment if i misunderstood your question. But if case like i said.

I have a solution which i was followed earlier in one of my work where infinite queues are created until desire results are delivered.

**Solution:**

I have created a **static** `NSInteger` variable to track limit the queue and recall them, And whenever i got desire result i check for that variable make it non negative or some limit check and then cancel all queues.

Hope this will help a little bit.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my question is about, and thanks for help, i found another solution to solved it, but really close to yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

NSOperationQueue *queue = userInfo[@"queue"];

[queue cancelAllOperations];
```