# How to remove operations from NSOperatinQueue in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

As I have used this concept to download multiple Images from Amazon S3 Bucket , how do I remove added Operation from NSOperationQueue while the process of downloading in progress?

And also, what should I do if in case I want to stop to download of all images while the process of downloading in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel all your queue operations using below line

```
[queue cancelAllOperations];
```

Also you can do this:

```
NSArray *operations = [queue operations];

for (NSOperation *op in operations) {
    if (!op.isCancelled) {
        [op cancel];
    }
}
```

But if you want to cancel your queue in between multiple requests then check my answer which will guide you to do so:

**[How to cancel operation queue in another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112710/how-to-cancel-operation-queue-in-another-view-controller/26113936#26113936)**

Comment: thank for answer but i want to stop all download operation, i already try with cancelAllOperations method but it did not work

Comment: thanks it works now i request for operation which is not cancelled

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation of your Operation you should check if the Operation is cancelled and stop the Operation. Please check the docs about Responding to the Cancel Command https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW18